# PySpark / Python / UserDefinedFunction / Redshift - Help required in ensuring an efficient query plan is used when using a UDF.

Tags: python, pyspark, udf

I have a quick question about the UserDefinedFunctions (udf) and the withColumn function to extend an extra column onto an existing SQL Data Frame.

For reference, I am querying data from RedShift.

If I use native JVM functions, for example pyspark.sql.functions.lower (which calls: org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower) the query that gets produced is clever to work out which columns to grab from the database.

```
(
    sql_context
    .read
    .format('com.databricks.spark.redshift')
    .option('url', URL)
    .option('dbtable', 'events')
    ...
    .withColumn('abc_lower', lower('abc'))  
    ...
)

# The query is:
('SELECT "abc" FROM events)
```

When I define my own function it is not so clever and grabs the whole table.

```
def foo_bar(abc):
    return abc[:-2]

foobar_udf = udf(foo_bar, StringType())

(
    sql_context
    .read
    .format('com.databricks.spark.redshift')
    .option('url', URL)
    .option('dbtable', 'events')
    ...
    .withColumn('abc_lower', foobar_udf('abc'))  
    ...
)

# The query is:
('SELECT "abc", "and", "every", "other", "column", "..." FROM events)
```

Any help on how I can stop it from doing this?

My one work around is to do a select before the withColumn, but I'd rather that Spark can work out which columns I need rather than having to say:

```
(
    sql_context
    .read
    .format('com.databricks.spark.redshift')
    .option('url', URL)
    .option('dbtable', 'events')
    ...
    .select(
        'abc',
        'other',
        'columns',
        'i',
        'want'
    )
    .withColumn('abc_lower', foobar_udf('abc'))  
    ...
)
# The query is:
('SELECT "abc", "other", "columns", "i", "want" FROM events)
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I've found that just using inbuilt functions - https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html is an acceptable way of making it more efficient, at least for simple functions.